# Create and pass a system identifier to a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

My main goal is to only create/output an xml element when it is **not** empty. If it is empty `NULL` should be returned. I'm using the native `xmlelement()` function for this. So if I call `SELECT xmlelement(name "my-element", NULL)` it will return `<my-element/>` while my goal is to return `NULL` in this case.

I tried to simply wrap the `xmlelement` function like below, so that it will return `NULL` when any input parameter is `NULL`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xml_noempty_element(label name, data xml) RETURNS xml AS
$$
SELECT xmlelement(label, data)
$$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Sadly this doesn't validate.

Is it even possible to create a PostgreSQL function that takes a system identifier? And if yes how can I create and pass the identifier/name to the function?

---

I know that I can do something like the following code to achieve my main goal:

```sql
SELECT CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT FROM my_xml_rows) THEN
    xmlelement(name "my-element",
      ( SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement) FROM my_xml_rows )
    )
END;
```

However this will call the query twice which I try to avoid.

I guess one other option I have is to wrap a `NULLIF((QUERY), '<my-element/>')` around.